# sql query help for the table below

Tags: oracle11g

my table structure is :
table_system:

```
"ID"               NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
"COUNTRY"          VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"COMPANYCODE"      VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"SYSTEM"           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"NOTSTARTED"       NUMBER,
"RUNNING"          NUMBER,
"COMPLETED"        NUMBER,
"ACTUALSTARTTIME"  VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
"ACTUALENDTIME"    VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
"SEQUENCE"         NUMBER,
"PLANNEDSTARTTIME" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
"PLANNEDENDTIME"   VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
"ESTIMATEDENDTIME" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
CONSTRAINT "SYSTEMRUNTIME_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "COUNTRY", "COMPANYCODE", "SYSTEM") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ENABLE
```

I need an output that will fetch me the following output:

```
COMPANYCODE                                         SYSTEM1 SYSTEM2 SYSTEM3 SYSTEM4 SYSTEM5 SYSTEM6 SYSTEM7 SYSTEM8 …   SYSTEM N
--------------------------------------------------  --------------------------- ------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------  ------------------------------  --------------------    --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------
```

where systems are sorted as per the "SEQUENCE" attribute.

I have tried this query :

```
    select distinct companycode, sequence, system,notstarted,running,completed
    from table_system
    where id = (select max(id) from table_system)
    order by companycode, sequence
```

this fetches me the following

```
COMPANYCODE SEQUENCE    SYSTEM  NOTSTARTED  RUNNING COMPLETED
--------------------------------------------------  ----------------------  --------------------------------------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
1001 Helsinki Branch    1   GAP 2 / Datastage GL    0   0   3
1001 Helsinki Branch    2   SAP GL  0   0   2
1001 Helsinki Branch    3   SAP BW  0   0   2
1002 Copenhagen Branch  1   GAP 2 / Datastage GL    0   0   3
1002 Copenhagen Branch  2   SAP GL  0   0   2
1002 Copenhagen Branch  3   SAP BW  0   0   2
1003 Oslo Branch    1   GAP 2 / Datastage GL    0   0   3
1003 Oslo Branch    2   SAP GL  0   0   2
1003 Oslo Branch    3   SAP BW  0   0   2
1004 (publ) (EUR)   1   EKO 0   0   13
1004 (publ) (EUR)   2   HA Core 0   0   6
1004 (publ) (EUR)   3   HA Post Processor   0   0   5
1004 (publ) (EUR)   4   Datastage GL    3   0   10
1004 (publ) (EUR)   5   Datastage Recon 1   0   3
1004 (publ) (EUR)   11  SAP GL  0   0   4
1004 (publ) (EUR)   21  SAP BW  0   0   4
```

but I want the output to be :

```
COMPANYCODE                                         SYSTEM1 SYSTEM2 SYSTEM3 SYSTEM4 SYSTEM5 SYSTEM6 SYSTEM7 SYSTEM8 …   SYSTEM N
--------------------------------------------------  --------------------------- ------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------  ------------------------------  --------------------    --------------  --------------  --------------  --------------
1001 Helsinki Branch            GAP 2 / Datastage GL    SAP GL  SAP BW                          
1002 Copenhagen Branch          GAP 2 / Datastage GL    SAP GL  SAP BW                          
1003 Oslo Branch                GAP 2 / Datastage GL    SAP GL  SAP BW                          
1004 (publ) (EUR)                       EKO HA Core HA Post Processor   Datastage GL    Datastage Recon SAP GL  SAP BW
```

Any hint for the above will be highly appreciated.
Thank You
vinayak

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
select companycode, COLLECT(system) as systems
    from table_system
    where id = (select max(id) from table_system)    
    group by companycode
    order by companycode, sequence
```

Comment: You need `COLLECT(system ORDER BY sequence)`, and to not have `sequence` in the main `order by clause`. And this assumes the client can handle the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [pivot](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#sthref6775) operation for this; but can't have an unknown number of systems to handle (as you need to know the number of selected columns at parse time):

```
select * from
(
    select companycode, system,
        row_number() over (partition by id, country, companycode
            order by sequence) as rn
    from table_system
    where id = (select max(id) from table_system)
)
pivot (max(system) for rn in (1 as system1, 2 as system2, 3 as system3,
    4 as system4, 5 as system5, 6 as system6, 7 as system7, 8 as system8))
order by company code;


COMPANYCODE                                        SYSTEM1                                            SYSTEM2                                            SYSTEM3                                            SYSTEM4                                            SYSTEM5                                            SYSTEM6                                            SYSTEM7                                            SYSTEM8
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1001 Helsinki Branch                               GAP 2 / Datastage GL                               SAP GL                                             SAP BW
1002 Copenhagen Branch                             GAP 2 / Datastage GL                               SAP GL                                             SAP BW
1003 Oslo Branch                                   GAP 2 / Datastage GL                               SAP GL                                             SAP BW
1004 (publ) (EUR)                                  EKO                                                HA Core                                            HA Post Processor                                  Datastage GL                                       Datastage Recon                                    SAP GL                                             SAP BW
```

So you'd need to establish the maximum number of systems you'll ever have present, and add clauses to the pivot (`9 as system9, ...`) to accommodate them all. The `row_number()` translates the sequence numbers into a contiguous number, so you don't have a big gap between the 5th and 6th systems for company `1004`; apart from anything else you'd need the pivot to handle the maximum possible sequence number rather than the maximum count of systems.